# How to write Android Youtube widget like 3d moving windows code

Tags: android

I want to create an application which is similar to the Android Youtube/Photo Gallery like widget which shows the Windows/Dialogs stacked on top of each other ? I am confused as to what should be the approach. Should i use Fragment dialogs ? How do i achieve the functionality of flipping the windows down or side ways one after the other ? I need some pointers please.

Regards
Ram

Answer (score 1):

well you may want to check the android transition layout `StackView` which will do what you asking for.